# Priority Level for Hidden Windows in Win7 or Win2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, boost-thread, thread-priority

For Windows 7 and/or Windows Server 2008, is there any specific difference in thread priority level or class between hidden windows and visible windows? In other words does the OS deprioritize the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference between visible and hidden, but on workstation systems the foreground application gets a [priority boost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (This can be [tweaked](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259025) on both server and workstation)

Answer (score 0):

No, the priority doesn't change.

Comment: So what would change? I am noticing a weird issue with Webbrowser control and a webpage containing flash, when the application is not visible. Flash makes requests to load images and xml files, and it seems like when the window is visible they load fine - when is hidden, it takes an additional 200-500ms to issue the requests! Same can be seen on IE8, if you minimize the browser window while loading the page.